# jQuery - ASP RadioButtonList: How do you get value attribute?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

I am using an ASP `RadioButtonList` with `ListItem` elements inside. I have given each option value. See below as an example:

```
<asp:RadioButtonList ID="rblTestList" runat="server">
    <asp:ListItem Selected="True" Text="Test1" Value="Test1" />
    <asp:ListItem Text="Test2" Value="Test2" />
    <asp:ListItem Text="Test3" Value="Test3" />
    <asp:ListItem Text="Test4" Value="Test4" />
</asp:RadioButtonList>
```

I am trying to get the value of the selected `ListItem`. I am using the following line of code to get the value, but all I get is the value 1 (not the text value I gave it). The API says the `Value` property is of type `String`, so I see cannot see why it isn't working. (See: [ListItem.Value Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listitem.value%28v=vs.110%29.aspx))

```
var option = $('#<%=rblTestList.ClientID %> input[type=radio]:checked').val();
```

Does anyone know what the issue is here?

Edit: Updated code snippet (old one was wrong)

Comment: I get `Test1` instead of 1 with the above code.

Comment: That's interesting. Do you think this is some configuration issue on the server?

Comment: If possible, view source of the generated page and post what you see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out it was related to resource keys. I had initially used numbers and then changed to text but the resource keys were not updated so it always priority over the inline value attribute. I missed out the resource key part in my snippet as I thought it wasn't important. My mistake. Sorry for wasting everyone's time!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$('document').ready(function () {
    $('#<%=rblTestList.ClientID%>').click(function () {
      if($(this).is(':checked')){
        var selectedValue = $(this).val();            
        alert(selectedValue);
      }
    });
});
```

**UPDATE 1:**

It's a server side control and here you need to find the input radio control first and check for it's check or uncheck property.

Try this Update

```
$('document').ready(function () {
        $('#<%=rblTestList.ClientID%>').find('input[type=radio]').click(function () {
          if($(this).is(':checked')){
            var selectedValue = $(this).val().replace('Test','');            
            alert(selectedValue);
          }
        });
});
```

**UPDATE 2**

if you want the numeic output then you have to put the options value in numeric like `Value="1"`.

**The HTML**

```
<asp:RadioButtonList ID="rblTestList" runat="server">
    <asp:ListItem Selected="True" Text="Test1" Value="1" />
    <asp:ListItem Text="Test2" Value="2" />
    <asp:ListItem Text="Test3" Value="3" />
    <asp:ListItem Text="Test4" Value="4" />
</asp:RadioButtonList>
```

The jquery code remains same as in UPDATE 1

Comment: I don't get any value when I try this - no alert box comes up at all

Comment: I get the values now but still only numeric (e.g. 1,2,3,4) and not the text version I supplied. Someone else tried my earlier code and got it fine so it sounds like some configuration issue - I just don't know what it would be. Very peculiar

Comment: value in your options are Test1, Test2 etc,, then how can you get 1 instead of Test1. or if you want then see my updated answer.

Comment: OK it looks like it could be something else wrong with my page because I tried your updated code (and my original) and it works fine on that other page.

Comment: It turned out it was related to resource keys. I had initially used numbers and then changed to text but the resource keys were not updated so it always priority over the inline value attribute. I missed out the resource key part in my snippet as I thought it wasn't important. My mistake. Sorry for wasting your time!

Answer (score 0):

Use Checkbox On Change Event to Get Value

```
$('#<%=rblTestList.ClientID%>').on('change',function () {
  if($(this).is(':checked')){ //Checks Checked or Not
    var Value = $(this).val(); //Here Your Value
  }              
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
     $(function () {
                $(".Jqanchor").click(function () {               
                    var option = $('# input[type=radio]:checked').next().text();
                    alert(option);
                });

            })
```

and aspx

```
<asp:RadioButtonList ID="rblTestList" runat="server">
        <asp:ListItem Selected="True" Text="Test1" Value="1" />
        <asp:ListItem Text="Test2" Value="2" />
        <asp:ListItem Text="Test3" Value="3" />
        <asp:ListItem Text="Test4" Value="4" />
    </asp:RadioButtonList>
    <a href="#" class="Jqanchor">content</a>
```